# C++ search for words string

Tags: c++, search, for-loop, words

I want to create program which will go through sentence and if it finds a character or a word it will display it.

Think of a program that stops as soon as it find first character/word.

```
   string test("This is sentense i would like to find ! "); //his is sentense to be searched
   string look; // word/char that i want to search

   cin >> look;

   for (i = 0; i < test.size(); i++) //i<string size
    {
       unsigned searcher = test.find((look));
       if (searcher != string::npos) {
           cout << "found at : " << searcher;
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the loop. Just do:

```
std::cin >> look;
std::string::size_type pos = test.find(look);
while (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    // Found!
    std::cout << "found at : " << pos << std::endl;
    pos = test.find(look, pos + 1);
}
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx%2461) showing the result for the input string `"is"`.

Comment: Yes but it wont go through whole sentence. E.g. if i try to search for char "e" it will find it just on 9th position.

Comment: @user2114862: Oh, so you want to look for all the occurrences?

Comment: Yes, so it should find char "e" 3 times and display positions.

Comment: I have one more question. Why do you use std:: with strings? If you know some www with explanation it would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: @user2114862: That is the namespace inside which class `string` is defined. The `::` is a scope resolution operator, and it basically tells the compiler to look up the name that comes after inside the namespace that comes before. If you have a `using namespace std;` directive in your program, names from the `std` namespace will be automatically imported, so you do not need to use the `std::` qualification. However, having a `using namespace std;` directive is considered **bad** programming practice, because it could lead to name clashes. Try to use explicit namespace qualification if possible